# How to improve the quality of JPEG images that are generated from PDFs using Ghostscript?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, jpeg, ghostscript

I use this code to generate JPEG images from a PDF file:

```
String cmd = @"./lib/gswin32c";
String args = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=jpeg -dJPEGQ=100 -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=" + fileName + "-%03d.jpg " + fileName + ".pdf";
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = cmd;
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.Start();
```

I works really fine, but the quality is really bad. It seems to be blurred. Any hints how to improve the quality?

### EDIT

Now I'm using the following arguments and it is working as expected:

```
String args = "-dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r300 -dBATCH -dSAFER -sOutputFile=" + fileName + "-%03d" + FILEEXTENSION + " " + fileName + ".pdf";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPEG? For *documents*? Generate gifs or pngs, if you can. JPEGs are unsuitable for anything else than photos, even at a "maximum" quality setting.

http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/

Comment: Thanks, now I used -sDEVICE=png16m but I can't see a difference. The quality is still quite blurry.

Comment: @Roflcoptr, just noticed that you're using a default DPI (which is 72). Add `-r300` or whatever, to get a better resolution.

Comment: Thanks, now it is working as expected. I edited my question and included the arguments I'm using now.

Answer (score 1):

I've quickly look through the [document](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/doc/cvs/Use.htm) and it seems there are some options to affect image quality like `-dCOLORSCREEN` and `-dDOINTERPOLATE`. Try them! :)

Comment: Thanks, it is better now, but not yet sufficient ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have just been struggling with the quality of a pdf to jpeg and have changed on the advice of dk-logic to gif.

This may help someone because I now have near perfect quality with the following command

```
gs -sDEVICE=png16m -r600 -dDownScaleFactor=3 -o outfile.png inFile.pdf
```

According the the docs

> **-dDownScaleFactor**=integer
>
> This causes the internal rendering to be scaled down by the given
>   (small integer) factor before being output.
>   For example, the above will produce a 200dpi output png from a
>   600dpi internal rendering: